# What should be the username and password for a path attack

Tags: security, authentication, path, passwords, information-extraction

A not-so-secure login system stores user passwords in "/userdata/passwords/". So, when Alice tries to log in with her username "alice" and her password, it goes and reads "/userdata/passwords/alice", and compares it to the provided password.

Furthermore – and this might be relevant later – we know that this login system is installed on a computer running MyOS, and that this operating system is known to have a file with its version - in this case, 1.0.3 - in "/system/version.txt".

Can you devise some credentials that will log you into the system, without knowing any legitimate usernames or passwords?

Please help I am having difficulty understanding this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are being asked to exploit a [path traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal) vulnerability. The article has IMHO all the information you need to have to solve the problem. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i am still having difficulties relating to it so could you just give me a possible username and password so that i could take that in relation and understand the steps to solve these types of question. Thank you

Comment: Try with the name `../../system/version.txt`. You know the password.

Comment: Thanks a lot I finally understood the concept behind this and was able to solve all other questions as well. Your previously sent link was really helpful.